# Desabilitar data no Datepicker vinda de tabela SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp, jquery-ui, datepicker

Estou com um sistema em ASP Clássico, em que tenho um calendário de agendamento.
Preciso desabilitar as datas que constam na tabela de feriados e compensações (id_feriado e data).
Não sei como fazer esse select para popular um array de datas indisponíveis.

Para fazer algo parecido com a linha da variável **unavailableDates**.

```
var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
var unavailableDates = ["2012/03/26","2012/03/27","2012/04/05"]; // yyyy/MM/dd**
var unavailableDays = ["Saturday","Sunday"];

function unavailable(date) {
ymd = date.getFullYear() + "/" + ("0"+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0"+date.getDate()).slice(-2);
day = new Date(ymd).getDay();
if ($.inArray(ymd, unavailableDates) < 0 && $.inArray(days[day], unavailableDays) < 0) {
    return [true, "enabled", "Book Now"];
} else {
    return [false,"disabled","Booked Out"];
}
}

$('#iDate').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: unavailable });
```

Comment: Você está usando o *datepicker* do jQuery UI?

Comment: não conheço outro datepicker com o option "beforeShowDay"

Comment: mmooser, postei a resposta abaixo para tentar lhe ajudar com o script, mas acredito que a sua duvida real seja como popular o array `unavailableDates` com os feriados, neste caso vou pedir para você colocar a estrutura da tabela de feriados.

Comment: Toby, minha dúvida é em relação à popular o array sim. Colocando as datas manualmente eu consigo, mas como não são somente os feriados, fica complicado eu ter que mudar o arquivo toda a vez.
A tabela tb_feriados tem a seguinte estrutura:
id_feriado - int (autonumerado)
data - datetime

Comment: "não são somente os feriados", o que mais então?

Comment: São datas específicas, como por exemplo recesso de fim de ano. Além dos feriados.

Answer (score 1):

mmooser, segue um exemplo um pouco mais limpo:

```js
var diasSemana = [ "Domingo", "Segunda", "Terca", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sabado" ];
var diasFinalSemana = [ "Domingo", "Sabado" ];

var datasIndisponiveis = [
    new Date(2015, 07, 26),
    new Date(2015, 07, 27),
    new Date(2015, 08, 05)
].map(function (data) {
    return data.getTime();
});

$('[date-datepicker]').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(data){        
        var diaSemana = diasSemana[data.getDay()];
        var isDataIndisponivel = datasIndisponiveis.indexOf(data.getTime()) != -1;
        var isDataFinalSemana = diasFinalSemana.indexOf(diaSemana) != -1;
        return [!isDataIndisponivel && !isDataFinalSemana];
    }
});
```

```css
.ui-widget {
    font-size: 70% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" date-datepicker="" />
```

Comment: Alguém sabe como preencher o array automaticamente?